# Can someone please explain why my google services and my data optimizer are using so much data?

Tags: google, mobile-data

Can someone please explain why my google services and my data optimizer are using so much data? This is ridiculous. Here is a link: http://m.imgur.com/TwiuCoL

Comment: What phone? And are you using a custom ROM?

Comment: @ak11 it is an lg g3 running android 5. Its not rooted so its stock lollipop

Comment: Not sure if this will help/work for you,, but you _may_ be able to check exactly what is using the data. http://www.howtogeek.com/206062/how-to-check-manage-and-clear-data-stored-by-google-play-services/